# Add related products to shortcode in Elementor

Tags: php, woocommerce, shortcode, elementor

I have an **updated woocommerce related products function** in my `function.php` file. I'd like to **add it to an Elementor `shortcode`** so I can have **multiple related products sections** on the product page template.

Can anyone advise how to make this work within an **Elementor shortcode**?

**Current `functions.php` Code**

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products', 'related_products_by_attribute', 10, 3 );
function related_products_by_attribute( $related_posts, $product_id, $args ) {
    $taxonomy   = 'pa_brand'; // HERE define the targeted product attribute taxonomy

    $term_slugs = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, $taxonomy, ['fields' => 'slugs'] ); // Get terms for the product

    if ( empty($term_slugs) )
        return $related_posts;

    $posts_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'            => 'product',
        'ignore_sticky_posts'  => 1,
        'posts_per_page'       => 4,
        'post__not_in'         => array( $product_id ),
        'tax_query'            => array( array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $term_slugs,
        ) ),
        'fields'  => 'ids',
        'orderby' => 'rand',
    ) );

    return count($posts_ids) > 0 ? $posts_ids : $related_posts;
}
add_shortcode( 'my_elementor_php_output', 'related_products_by_attribute');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Elementor's shortcode element and paste this in the field:

```
[my_elementor_php_output]
```